# PHP strtotime dilema

Tags: php, strtotime

Can someone explain why this outputs true on my server?

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Bucharest');    
var_dump( strtotime('29.03.2015 03:00', time()) ===  strtotime('29.03.2015 04:00', time()));
```

Can't get my head around it

Comment: The only thing I can think of is, because on this day you will lose 1h because of the change to summertime! (In which timezone are you?)

Comment: Edited: timezone is gmt+2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I thought it's because of the time change to summertime as you can see here: http://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/romania/bucharest

So if it is 03:00 the time gets set 1h forward to 04:00

Comment: So why 04:00 is not forwaded 1h ? Sorry if it's dumb question

Comment: @Vodaldrien At 3 o'clock AM the time gets set 1h forward so you will lose 1h and it's 4 o'clock AM in the morning and you do this only at 3 o'clock not on 4 o'clock in your timezone